# Add custom data field column to relationship tab

Tags: relationships, contact-view

Is there a way to add additional field(s) in the relationship tab on a contacts record?

as " [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/) is not getting triggered for relationship.
( though this hook is helpful for contribution tab and other search results.)

can any one please advice what would be best way forward to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the pages that you would expect to support `hook_civicrm_searchColumns` don't - they're mostly older screens that don't use the appropriate shared code.

Ideally, we would rewrite these pages to use `CRM_Core_Selector_Query` so the hook fires.  Since that's not often feasible within a budget, I've resorted to using template overrides, with API calls within the override to pull in additional data.

If you want to avoid overrides, you could probably use JavaScript includes.

None of these are perfect, but short of rewriting the screens (a noble goal!) this is what we have to work with!

Comment: Thanks Jon. May be I'll try with template override with API calls. Thanks for quick response :) I really appreciate it. :)